# Server data coming through as [Object object] on client

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, client-server

[image]

I'm trying to display my data being sent from the server but it's not coming through properly (see [Object object] in the bottom left of the image above). Here's the client side code:

```
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title"><%= event.event_name %></h5>
          <p class="card-text"><%= event.description %></p>
          <p class="card-text"><%= eventData %></p>
        </div>
```

The server is sending the data in an array in below format:

```
 const eventData = [{
      _id: 'objectId_for_the_event',
      guests: [
          'guestId1',
          'guestId2', 
          'guestId3',
          'guestId4',
          'guestId5'
       ],
       totalGuests: 5,
       attendedGuests: 0
      }
     ]
```

I *want* the values from totalGuests and attendedGuests to display on the client. Here's my function in the server (it's long and a little confusing but that console.log in the last line works perfectly, so the variables are working):

```
module.exports.showEvent = async (req, res) => {
    const event = await Event.findById(req.params.id).populate('artist');
    const { guest_id } = req.cookies;
    let totalGuests = 0;
    let attendedGuests = 0;
    const eventData = await Event.aggregate([
        {
            "$match": {
                "_id": objectId(req.params.id)
            }
        },
        {
            $project: {
                _id: 1,
                name: 1,
                guests: 1,
                totalGuests: { $cond: { if: { $isArray: "$guests" }, then: { $size: "$guests" }, else: "NA" } },
                attendedGuests: {
                    $size: {
                        $filter: {
                            input: "$guests",
                            as: "guest",
                            cond: {
                                $and: [{
                                    $eq: ["$$guest.attended", "Y"]
                                }]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ])
    if (eventData && Array.isArray(eventData) && eventData.length > 0) {
        totalGuests = eventData[0].totalGuests;
        attendedGuests = eventData[0].attendedGuests;
    }
    if (!event) {
        req.flash('error', 'Cannot find that Event');
        return res.redirect('/events');
    }
    res.render('events/show', { event, eventData });
    console.log(totalGuests, attendedGuests);
};
```

How do I get those two variables *out* of the array and onto the client?

Comment: You need to use `JSON.stringify()` on your variables first before sending them

Comment: That was it! Thanks @Capt171 - will add separately in an answer unless you want the credit?     const attendees = JSON.stringify(attendedGuests); in the function and               <p class="card-text"><%= attendees %></p> on the client

Comment: Will add an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `JSON.stringify()` to stringify the values before sending them. It would be something like this:

```js
JSON.stringify(attendedGuests);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the first object in the array instead of the array itself:

`res.render('events/show', { event, eventData[0] });`.

You can also destructure it like `const [{totalGuests, attendedGuests}] = eventData;` and then send those two variables as `totalGuests` and `attendedGuests`

Comment: Tried the fist method and the syntax was off once I added the [0]. All my code below that row would error out. Also, eventData is already declared but took part of your idea and just declared totalGuests and attendedGuests in their own stringified variable. Posting answer separately but thanks for the feedback @yaezah !